# Getting crash when "<null>" as response from api is received in SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Getting the image url null as response from api, is there any way for fix it. Response from api is:

```
"image_path" = "<null>";
```

Tried to handle it like this:

```
if !(arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("media")?.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("image_path") is NSNull) {
            // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
        }
```

It is still crashing please guide.
Update:

Found the problem, null was not the issue actually. Posting the response below to make things clear.

```
media =             (
                            {
                id = "97eb48a0-429a-11e6-873c-ad7b848648f1";
                "image_path" = "https://s3-eu-west-1.mazws.com/facebook_profile_images/15105131.png";
                "room_post_id" = "97c572e0-429a-11e6-b72b-fd489f63a1fc";
                "user_id" = "66fe22a0-4296-11e6-a1d9-69dc307add4b";
                "video_path" = "<null>";
            },
                            {
                id = "981a6880-429a-11e6-b039-736a0bf954dc";
                "image_path" = "<null>";
                "room_post_id" = "97c572e0-429a-11e6-b72b-fd489f63a1fc";
                "user_id" = "66fe22a0-4296-11e6-a1d9-69dc307add4b";
                "video_path" = "https://s3-eu-west-1.naws.com/facebook_profile_images/1255803.mp4";
            }
        );
```

This is the normal response, now the response where trouble is:

```
media =             (
        );
```

Can it be handle any how? Please guide.

Comment: try `if let` or `guard` statement

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Can you please elaborate or give some example like to understand

Comment: possibly image_path getting as string "<null>" so that is treating as String but not null the value.

Comment: i also thought so but string check also doesn't work.

Comment: Than you can handle it as if there is string than that will be a valid path otherwise that should be treated as no image.

Comment: Try the code that i post in answer

Comment: Please give us the full json output, your `if` accesses a lot of inner fields, any of them can crash. Also please post the crash details.

Comment: @Cristik Posted please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this .. it'll not crash

```
if let imgPath = arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("media")?.objectAtIndex(0).valu‌​eForKey("image_path") as? String {

//... your value is string 

}
```

Comment: than you need to check one by one object creation.. I'm changing

Comment: It is giving error "Value of type Any Object" has no member "ValueForKey"

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess types by information you provided:

```
if let arrList = arrList as? NSArray,
    firstObject = arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary,
    media = firstObject.valueForKey("media") as? NSArray,
    secondObject = media.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSDictionary,
    image_path = secondObject.valueForKey("image_path") as? String {

    print(image_path)
    // now validate your string
}
```

Validating your string can be like this:

```
if !image_path.isEmpty && image_path != "<null>" {
    //do something
}
```

or like this:

```
if !image_path.isEmpty {
    if let image_pathURL = NSURL(string: image_path), _ = image_pathURL.host {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Of I got idea from your code when debugged came to know exactly the cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't to simple check with == like:

```
if !(arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("media")?.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("image_path") == "<null>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let image = myJson["image_path"] as? String {
  imageView.image = image
}
else {
  imageview.image = "default.png"
}
```

also try this

```
if !(arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("media")?.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("image_path") == "<null>") {
            // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
        }
```

Comment: if !((arrList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("media")?.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("image_path"))! as! String == "<null>") {
                // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
            }

Comment: this way also crashed